# Communicating with an external service: internal server error 500

Tags: internal-server-error, actions-on-google, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to make a GET request to an HTTPS service ( https://broker.bronos.net ). This service is an API that communicates with a client on my LAN. I can't get it to work via `functions.https.get(URL, (s,ss) => {});`

Please help -- I'm very new to web development, let alone google actions.

I'm using the apiai-starter-app as the base, which functions perfectly fine until I add the line above which returns internal server error 500.

Note: I've tried before adding billing to the project and after as well. Neither work.

Edit: 
using this

```
        const https = require('https');

https.get('https://broker.bronos.net/v1/CLIENT_ID/ROOM_NAME/ACTION/PARAM', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
            if (requestSource === googleAssistantRequest) {
        sendGoogleResponse(JSON.parse(data).explanation); // Send simple response to user
      } else {
        sendResponse(JSON.parse(data).explanation); // Send simple response to user
      }
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
                if (requestSource === googleAssistantRequest) {
        sendResponse("Error: " + err.message); // Send simple response to user
      } else {
        sendResponse("Error: " + err.message); // Send simple response to user
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's functions have limited access to external APIs on the free tier. By upgrading to [Blaze or Flame plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) you will be able to make external API calls.

Enabling Firebase Blaze plan + the following code worked

```
        const https = require('https');

https.get('https://broker.bronos.net/v1/CLIENT_ID/Living%20Room/volume/20', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
            if (requestSource === googleAssistantRequest) {
        sendGoogleResponse(JSON.parse(data).explanation); // Send simple response to user
      } else {
        sendResponse(JSON.parse(data).explanation); // Send simple response to user
      }
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
                if (requestSource === googleAssistantRequest) {
        sendResponse("Error: " + err.message); // Send simple response to user
      } else {
        sendResponse("Error: " + err.message); // Send simple response to user
      }
});
```

Comment: I guess I'll try again, but just like I stated at the end, I tried with the blaze plan and without. Didn't seem to work.

Comment: I had to fix my code on top of it. I marked you as the correct answer since technically speaking if my code had been correct that would've been my issue.